# my Texshop file runs in my old mac but not in the new one, what can I do to be able to compile the document in my new computer?

Tags: mac, texshop, mactex

My .tex file compiles without problem in my previous MacBook Pro, but it doesn't compile in the new MacBook Pro, even tho I have installed MacTex, what can I do? Please help :( I haven't been able to start using my new computer because of this (it's been more than a month since I bought it

I have checked that all packages are installed, but that didn't work

Comment: Can you show your .log file?

Comment: It is a very long file, is there anything in particular that would be useful to share?

Comment: up to (and including) the first error would be good

Comment: If you cross-post the same question on multiple sites, you should include links to all other versions of the question in every question. X-posting without explicit links has the risk of wasting both the time of users who might put time and effort into answering a post, which already has an answer elsewhere, as well as the time of users who might have the same problem but can't find the solutions you might have gotten on one of the other sites you x-posted your question

Comment: x-post https://stackoverflow.com/q/78203733/2777074